# How can I check for radar on 5 GHz DFS channels?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I had set a 5 GHz Wi-Fi AP to use DFS channels and it didn't go well. To understand whether this was due to getting signals from privileged sources (i.e. radar), I'd like to have a way to listen for radar signal on the channels.

Unfortunately, the AP itself is a shiny amazing ISP-provided brick that will let me do basically nothing beyond basic configuration, so I can't access its logs to check for DFS events there. Is there another way to check, using Linux/Windows/Android or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

To check for non-WiFi signals, you generally can't use the built-in hardware. The hardware that's built into your devices only does WiFi and it can't detect any other signals. Some provide some "interference" metric, but that's it.

To properly check, you need some sort of generic receiver, preferably a spectrum analyzer. A relatively cheap option is a<strike>n RTL-SDR USB dongle</strike> HackRF, with a 5GHz antenna. This will allow you to observe the spectrum around the 5GHz WiFi channels.

Radar should show up as a wide strong signal:
[image]

Another option is to contact your local HAM radio club or a local HAM operator. They will most definitely have the equipment to look for local interference and are more than likely to be willing to help you out.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to make a cheap RTL-SDR do 5GHz, and especially not at 80 or 160MHz wide. I'm pretty sure the people doing 5GHz with 80MHz widths with SDR are using expensive professional SDRs like Ettus Research USRPs that cost $1000 and up. Even with that equipment, you'd still probably be unable to tell whether or not the energy you're seeing is radar vs. non-radar 5GHz energy.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. I mixed up the RTL-SDR with the HackRF, which does go up to 6GHz. If there is continuous interference, you wouldn't have to monitor the entire WiFi channel all the time, so 20MHz bandwidth would be plenty.

Answer (score 3):

If you were just looking for interference in general, not specifically radar signals triggering DFS channel switches, a 5GHz spectrum analyzer, such as a MetaGeek Wi-Spy DBx, would do. However, a spectrum analyzer mostly just graphs how much energy it sees on various frequencies over time, without actually being able to differentiate between Wi-Fi, radar, and other things that use 5GHz. So it wouldn't give you any insight into whether radar-triggered DFS channel switch events are happening.

If you specifically want to see if your equipment is detecting radar on DFS channels and switching channels because of it, you should enable verbose logging on the Wi-Fi subsystems/drivers of your APs and client devices, and watch for radar/DFS/channel-switch events in the logs (the details on how to do this can vary wildly between platforms and Wi-Fi chipsets, and is beyond the scope of this question).

Another thing you could do is log what channel you see your AP on, and see if you ever see it change channels. Make sure you're checking what channel it's actually using, not what channel you asked it to try to use.

Comment: Logging on the AP is unfortunately out of the question, but I may look into logging on the clients which I have full control over. Does the AP send a notification of DFS or is it simply a notification of channel change for unspecified reasons?

 I've noticed the AP doesn't want to stay on the channels I told it to (which were DFS channels), hence the question in the first place: To find out whether this is due to DFS or some other fault.